# How to set up Sitecore 8.1 MVC project with multiple website

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, tds, sitecore8.1

I am planning to set up a Sitecore 8.1 MVC project for 2 website in one visual studio solution so which approach should I follow:

**Approach 1:**

Should I create two MVC project in one solution

Sample.SC.Model ( C# class library )

Sample.SC.Utility ( C# class library )

Sample.SC.Web.Website1 ( MVC project ) ( This project will contains layout,sublayout and everything specific to Website1 )

Sample.SC.Web.Website2 ( MVC project ) ( This project will contains layout,sublayout and everything specific to Website2 )

**Aproach 2:**

Should I create only one MVC project and put the Website1 layout and Website1 sublayout in Website1 folder and Website2 layout and Website2 sublayout in Website2 folder

Sample.SC.Model ( C# class library )

Sample.SC.Utility ( C# class library )

Sample.SC.Web.Website ( MVC project )

****Folder structure under Sample.SC.Web.Website node****

Layout

Website1 ( will contains layout specific to Website1 )

Website2 ( will contains layout specific to Website2 )

Sublayout

Website1 ( will contains sublayout specific to Website1 )

Website2 ( will contains sublayout specific to Website1 )

I am also planning to use GlassMapper and TDS in this project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a compelling technical reason to choose one approach over the other, but I don't think there is one.

Ultimately both approaches once deployed will result in a single website. While people have different preferences, both will work.

Much of it will come down to the similarities and differences between the sites. Are they completely separate and unrelated? If so then you might find option 1 preferable because there will be less clutter per project.

However, if the two sites will share elements then it might be simpler to manage using option 2.

I don't think the use of TDS/Glass should really influence your decision either way.

Comment: I am in little doubt in Approach 1 that we are creating two MVC project in one solution.Is there will be any issue if we host these two website in IIS.

Comment: Not sure about that. Here's Sitecore advice on multiple IIS (Not MVC specific) sites https://goo.gl/29HOh5

Comment: OK but when I clicked on goo.gl/29HOh5 link it shows following message:
The requested document was not found.

Comment: The most compelling reason for not hosting two separate IIS sites is licensing. Normally one IIS site = one Sitecore license. Be sure to check the terms of your licensing agreement.

Comment: @JammyKam Agreed. I think maybe I misunderstood the question, but my answer assumes that both approaches will deploy to a single IIS site.

Comment: @MartinDavies Your answer is sound, I was replying to the first comment from the OP.

Comment: @Martin: Actually Approach 1 contains two MVC web project so How approache 1 will deploy to a single IIS site.
but I agree that approache 2 will deploye to single IIS site because it contains only one MVC web project.
Please correct me If I'm wrong...

Comment: @Sukhi It's possible with multiple projects: http://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/07/10/sitecore-solution-structure/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use in this case Sitecore Areas. 
You will have a structure like in below picture:

[image]

More informations about Sitecore 8.1 Areas you can find [here](http://ctor.io/new-in-sitecore-8-1-mvc-areas/)

Under the Views forlder you will have 2 subfolders: Layout and Sublayout. 
I suggest to not name folder Sublayout because if is a MVC solution you are not using Sublayout you will use views. 
This is the structure for the Website project (Sample.SC.Web.Website) 
You can create how many projects on your solution, but I don't suggest to have projects just for models for example. Models can be added under the Areas folder.

Comment: I clicked on link provided under here text but it shows me image file only

Comment: I updated my answer, my ideea is to use Areas not to add new projects, or   new folders if you are using MVC.

Comment: See also http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2015/10/Sitecore-8%20-1-MVC-Improvements-Area-Support-and-MVC-5-2-3.aspx for more about Area Support.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 1, for the following reasons:

- you won't be able to migrate one site to another Sitecore installation in the future, as the source files are tied together. When going with solution 2, that will be a *lot* of work, depending on how big your website and solution will grow. Only if you are like 300% sure that that will not happen in the future
- The development lifecycle for both sites will be tied together very thightly: When there are reasons to iterate quickly for one site, that will be much harder.

To prevent duplicate files, make sure to think on a good naming convention and folder structure and think of the shared components.

In the end, the deployment effort shouldn't be too large, especially when continuous deployment is in place.

Comment: OK but can you please let me know website hosting process in Approach 1 because it contains two MVC web project.

Comment: I would simply split it into 2 solutions, maybe 3. Keep all reusable components together and reference them in the two webapplication project. Now your free to have release cycles which are not tied to each other, except for the shared components.

Comment: for example we are going to host website1 in IIS so process will be:
1. add the reference of Model,Utility in website1.
2. publish the website somewhere in folder says PublishedWebsite1
3.create a virtual directory in IIS and map that to PublishedWebsite1
now we are hosting webiste2 in IIS so
1. add the reference of Model,Utility in website2
2. publish the website somewhere in folder says PublishedWebsite2
3.create a virtual directory in IIS and map that to PublishedWebsite2

In this way we can host two website.
Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second approach, I think the first approach need more efforts to implement because of the following reasons:

1. You will have to publish each site alone.
2. Probably you will have DLL for each site, and this something needs to take care of.
3. You have to take care of the files for both websites, so they will not be merged or replaced once you deploy. 
   as example: 
    Website1 > Css > site.css 
            Website2 > Css > site.css

Once you deploy these files will overwrite each other.

So I think you have to do something like this in each mvc project:

Website1 > WebsiteOneName  > Css > site.css

Website2 > WebsiteTwoName  > Css > Site.css

4. Each site will have the web.config file, and this is something you will need to take care of it. (One config file for both)

Comment: I am having little doubt because it has two MVC project so how to deploy Website1 on IIS

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 8.1 has already introduces Areas in Controller Rendering Template so now you can use MVCAreas in your MVC project to have a multisite implementation configured. And use the ResolveArea pipeline for resolving your areas as in below image [ResolveArea Pipeline configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NazUq.png)

For more information check [this](http://ctor.io/new-in-sitecore-8-1-mvc-areas/)